# How to make postgresql database connectable from outside of the postgres docker container?

Tags: linux, sockets, docker, debian

I am using postgres:9.3 docker container from the official docker hub

```
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
```

started the database container with command

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 25432:5432 --name osm-database osm-database
```

and connect to it using docker link from another container(osm-updater)

```
docker run -d --link osm-database --name osm-updater osm-updater
```

Now I found I can not psql to the database from osm-updater container, get error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.17.0.12" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

so I explored the network sockets within the **osm-database container** with

```
netstat -tulpn
```

the result

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

which shows within the osm-database container, the postgres db can only be connected to 127.0.0.1 which is wrong ? should be 0.0.0.0:5432 ?

so that I could not connect to osm-database from osm-update with command like

```
psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h 172.17.0.12
```

172.17.0.12 is the ip_address obtained with (docker inspect command)

How could I fix this ?  How could I change the "local address" column of the network socket

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use the eth0 of the machine. If you are in Linux you can grab it via `ifconfig` and connect to the database on port 25432 as that is the port you are exposing.